# React Updating Prop In Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal: Click a button in a child component and have that component removed.

New to React. In my app.js I have a component and a prop within that component:

```
<IntroSteps isHidden={false} />
```

In the `<IntroSteps>` component I have logic to listen for the `isHidden` Prop

```
export default function IntroSteps({isHidden}) {
if(isHidden) {
  return null
 }
  return ( <div> content </div> ) 
}
```

My goal is to be able to update isHidden within the IntroSteps component. I've attempted the following with no luck. What is the correct way to do this?

```
const removeIntroSteps = () => {
isHidden = true
};
```

Comment: Props are immutable So I'm afraid you might not be able to change it in the child component. What exactly do you wish to achieve btw?

Comment: I want to be able to click a button within the child component and have it removed from the dom

Comment: So you should pass this callback function that sets isHidden to true from the parent function and call it in the child component where you want to do so,

Comment: Yeah posted. See if that helps @AndrewLeonardi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you've clarified:

> want to be able to click a button within the child component and have it removed from the dom

The best way to do that is to have the child component call a function that the parent passes it, and have the parent either render the child (not hidden) or not render it (hidden) (or alternatively, render it with the `isHidden` flag and the child component can return `null` when `isHidden` is true, but that seems round-about).

Quick example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Child = ({hide}) => {
    return <div>
        I'm the child <input type="button" onClick={hide} value="Hide Me" />
    </div>;
};

const Example = () => {
    const [childHidden, setChildHidden] = useState(false);
    
    const hideChild = () => setChildHidden(true);

    return <div>
        {childHidden ? null : <Child hide={hideChild} />}
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

While you *can* add state to the child component that lets it maintain a separate flag (`hiddenMyself` for instance, then return `null` if either `isHidden` or `hiddenMyself` is true), you can't directly change the state of the `isHidden` prop. That's something the parent component controls, not the child.

Answer (score 1):

Props are immutable So I'm afraid you might not be able to change it in the child component. I'd rather do it this way:
In app.js

```
const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState[false];
const updateHidden =() =>{
 setIsHidden(!isHidden) //true or false
}
<IntroSteps isHidden={isHidden} updateHidden={updateHidden} />
```

Then in the child component,
simply call `updateHidden` wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

[Props are read-only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only), so you can't.

You need to pass a function to your component which is responsible for updating the state of isHidden.

In the IntroSteps, you need to add this for example:

```
const toggleIsHidden => setIsHidden(!isHidden);

<IntroSteps isHidden={false} toggleIsHidden={toggleIsHidden} />
```

Then, in your component:

```
export default function IntroSteps({isHidden, toggleIsHidden}) {

// use toggleIsHidden function as you need

if(isHidden) {
  return null
 }
  return ( <div> content </div> ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to pass 2 props into IntroSteps component.

```
isHidden, setIsHidden
```

Of course, these 2 variables could be defined in parent component by `useState`.

Code example:

```
export default function ParentComponent() {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(false);
  
  ...
  ...
  
  return (
    <IntroSteps isHidden={isHidden} setIsHidden={setIsHidden} />
  )
}
```